# js file ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

**I Try to use Laravel and Vue in my project.**

The Vue component(example) doesn't render.

and the error in the console is:

- GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
- GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I think the problem is in the src attribute **asset**

`<script src = "{{asset ('js / app.js')}}" defer> </script>`

I run - **composer require laravel/ui** again, and not working

The view - welcome.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel Vue</title>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <example></example>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The component

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">enter code here
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

The app.js

```
require("./bootstrap");

window.Vue = require("vue").default;

Vue.mixin(require("./asset"));

Vue.component("example", require("./components/Example.vue").default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vite": "^2.9.11",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4"
    },
}
```

Comment: Did you ran `npm run dev`?

Comment: I try to run: 
`npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead.

> dev
> vite


  vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 395ms.


  Laravel v9.19.0

  > APP_URL: http://localhost`

Comment: and get : 

This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: First of all, your assets must be loaded like so: `@vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])` and second your `npm run dev --watch` has to be constantly running.

Comment: vite.config :

`export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [laravel(["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"])],
});`

Comment: `run npm dev` not working

Comment: `npm run dev` and not `run npm dev`

Comment: yes sorry, I meant it. But it not wotk

Comment: What does it "says"?

Comment: can i send to you pic ?

the page :
`This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/
HTTP ERROR 404`